# Personal library application, allows user to add and remove books and update read status of an existing book

Tags: javascript

I have created my first crud javascript application to help me learn and I'm looking to hear from you any improvements or good practices I could apply to the code I've written.

In my html I have a bookshelf div and the html code needed for a form which pop-ups on the click of `addNewBook` button.

The code initially loads my library with two hard-coded books, and then allows the user to add new book to the library by filling the form.

Furthermore, each book has a remove from library option.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

class Book {
    constructor(title, author, pages, isRead, isNewlyAdded) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.isRead = isRead;
        this.isNewlyAdded = isNewlyAdded;
    }
    info() {
        return `Book name: ${this.title}. The author is ${this.author} and the number of pages is ${this.pages}.`;
    }
}

let myLibrary = [];
function addBookToLibrary(book) {
    myLibrary.push(book);
}

let hobbit = new Book("The hobbit", "Tolkien", 323, false, true);
let richDadPoorDad = new Book("Rich dad poor dad", "Kyosaki", 231, true, true);


function addFirstTwoBooks() {
    addBookToLibrary(hobbit);
    addBookToLibrary(richDadPoorDad);
}

const bookShelf = document.getElementById("bookshelf");
addFirstTwoBooks();

function render() {
    for (let i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
        if (myLibrary[i].isNewlyAdded) {
            myLibrary[i].isNewlyAdded = false;
            let newElement = document.createElement('div');
            newElement.className = "book-case";
            let title = document.createElement('p');
            title.innerHTML = `Book title: ${myLibrary[i].title}`;
            let author = document.createElement('p');
            author.innerHTML = `Book author: ${myLibrary[i].author}`;
            let numberOfPages = document.createElement('p');
            numberOfPages.innerHTML = `Number of pages: ${myLibrary[i].pages}`;
            let readStatus = document.createElement('button');
            readStatus.className = 'read-button';
            readStatus.innerHTML = `Read status: ${myLibrary[i].isRead}`;
            readStatus.addEventListener('click', function () {
                myLibrary[i].isRead = !myLibrary[i].isRead;
                readStatus.innerHTML = `Read status: ${myLibrary[i].isRead}`;
            })
            let removeButton = document.createElement('button');
            removeButton.innerHTML = "remove";
            removeButton.className = "remove-button";
            addInfoToElement(newElement, title, author, numberOfPages, readStatus, removeButton);
            newElement.id = `bookNumber:${i}`;
            bookShelf.appendChild(newElement);
            removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
                bookShelf.removeChild(newElement);
            })
        }
    };
}
render();
let addBookButton = document.createElement("button");
addBookButton.classList.add("newBookButton");
addBookButton.onclick = openForm;
addBookButton.textContent = "Click here to insert a new book";
body.appendChild(addBookButton);

function addInfoToElement(element, title, author, numberOfPages, readStatus, removeButton) {
    element.appendChild(title);
    element.appendChild(author);
    element.appendChild(numberOfPages);
    element.appendChild(readStatus);
    element.appendChild(removeButton);
}

function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("Form").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("Form").style.display = "none";
}

var form = document.getElementById('myForm');

function createNewBook() {
    let bookTitle = form.elements[0].value;
    let bookAuthor = form.elements[1].value;
    let numberOfPages = form.elements[2].value;
    let isRead = (form.elements[3].value === 'true');
    let userCreatedBook = new Book(bookTitle, bookAuthor, numberOfPages, isRead, isNewlyAdded = true);
    myLibrary.push(userCreatedBook);
    render();
}

function clearDom() {
    while (bookShelf.firstChild) {
        bookShelf.removeChild(bookShelf.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete because it lacks the description of what the code does. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient description to your question, preferably with an example session. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See [Questions should include a description of what the code does](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1231).

Comment: Thank you for you comment, I've added a description of what my code does now.